# How to add value to array element withing collection using mongoose?

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, angularjs-directive, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I have written the following mongoose function to create new document in mongodb

```
createdata: (body) => {
    let sEntry = new SData(Object.assign({}, {
        dataId: body.DataId
       //,
       //notes.message: body.message   
    }));
    return sEntry.save();
}
```

Here `sData` schema includes `notes` array schema within it.

I am not able to add value to `message` within `notes []` using `notes.message: body.message`

My schema definition is as follows:

```
var nSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type:ObjectId, auto: true },
    message: String
});

var sSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type:ObjectId, auto: true },
    dataId: { type:String, unique: true },
    notes: [nSchema]
}
```

I also want to mention that for every `dataId` there can be multiple `notes []` entries. However, `SData` can have only unique row entry for every `dataId`.

I want notes to be an array within `SData` collection. How it can be achieved without creating separate `notes` collection? How should i modify `createdata` to accommodate all the given requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `references` for other collection mapping and use `populate` when fetching

**Schema Design**

```
var sSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type:ObjectId, auto: true },
    dataId: { type:String, unique: true },
    notes: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'nSchema',
    }]
}
```

**Adding Data**

```
createdata: (body) => {
    let sEntry = new SData({
        dataId: body.DataId,
        notes: [nSchemaIds]
    });
    return sEntry.save();
}
```

Comment: should I create separate `create function` to add notes? Also, is `notes` going to be a separate collection?

Comment: Notes is a separate collection I assume that's what you want. Once notes inserted you add its reference to another collection

Comment: I want notes to be an array within `SData` collection. How it can be achieved without creating separate `notes` collection?